# How do I get my compiler to work in codelite? (It works with codeblocks)

Tags: c, compiler-errors, codelite

I am fairly new to programming and have mostly programmed using textfiles but now I am supposed to start using CodeLite for an assignment. I am using windows 10 64-bit.

The problem is that I cannot seem to get my compiler to work in codelite the error message I receive is this:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C C:/TDM-GCC-32/bin/mingw32-make.exe -j4 SHELL=cmd.exe -e -f  Makefile
"----------Building project:[ hello - Debug ]----------"
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'C:/codelitews/hello'
'makedir' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [Debug/.d] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
hello.mk:88: recipe for target 'Debug/.d' failed
built-in: fatal error: opening dependency file ./Debug/main.c.o.d: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [Debug/main.c.o.d] Error 1
hello.mk:99: recipe for target 'Debug/main.c.o.d' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/codelitews/hello'
mingw32-make.exe: *** [All] Error 2
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'All' failed

====1 errors, 0 warnings====
```

And I cannot figure out what this means and why it happens since the same compiler works just fine with codeblocks. I have tried googling this issue but have not found something useful. Help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You should use `mkdir` instead of `makedir`

Comment: try that and if there was any other error report it

Comment: Learn to compile one single file on the command line

Comment: @Ehsan I'm sorry for being newbish but I don't know how make it use `mkdir`instead of `makedir` could you explain?

Comment: put your makefile here

Comment: How do I find my makefile?

Answer (score 0):

CodeLite should be able to recognize `makedir.exe` it is located under the same folder where you installed `codelite.exe`

If it does not, then it means that something terribly went wrong, usually this happens when you start modifying the `PATH` environment variable without knowing what you are doing.

Can you please paste the content of your environment variable (from within CodeLite). From the main menu, go to: Settings->Environment Variables and paste here the content of the text box

Eran